# Playing game A deletes saved data of game B (Donkey Kong Country only) - how to fix?

Tags: snes, donkey-kong-country, donkey-kong-country-2

I have Donkey Kong Country and Donkey Kong Country 2: Diddy Kong Quest for the super nintendo. If I have saved data on one game and decide to switch the game I am playing, then the saved data from the previous game deletes. This has happened multiple times on a timespan of years. The problem is not reproducible if the switched game is not one of these Donkey Kong titles (unsure about Donkey Kong Country 3 since I do not own that game). I have read other posts on this site about how failing batteries can delete saved game data, but the saved data is fine if I opt to never play the other game - which is not ideal.

Is this a common problem and how can I resolve this?

Comment: So to be clear: you play (say) DKC 1, save the game (quit/restart your snes, play it again, etc. etc.) then when you insert DKC 2, play it and save it, your DKC 1 game erases?

Comment: Do a test. Play Donkey Kong Country and save the game. Remove the game from the snes. Play absolutely no other games. Let the cartridge sit there for a day or more. Play Donkey Kong Country and let me know if the saved game still exists. Also, are you making sure to turn off the snes before removing the game cartridge?

Comment: @schil227 That is correct.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I do make sure to turn off the console before removing the game. What would this test prove? I’d hate to lose saved data for a 102% game...

Comment: @allthemikeysaretaken (in reply to MonkeyZeus's suggestion) it would rule out the supposed connection between one game altering another's volatile memory. Really it's likely that the sporadic saved game erasing is due to the battery in the cartridge failing (see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/169202/118629).